# Google charts literal string tooltip error when applied to all fields

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pie-chart

this is pretty straightforward. 
This is based on the pie chart example on the [google charts playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart)

Can anyone tell me why this works:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 4],
    ['Eat', {'v':0.,'f':'text 2'}],
    ['Commute', {'v':2,'f':'text 3'}],
    ['Watch TV', {'v':2,'f':'text 4'}],
    ['Sleep', {'v':0.,'f':'text 5'}]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
}
```

But this doesn't (added a literal string for "Work" line):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', {'v':4,'f':'text 1'}],
    ['Eat', {'v':0.,'f':'text 2'}],
    ['Commute', {'v':2,'f':'text 3'}],
    ['Watch TV', {'v':2,'f':'text 4'}],
    ['Sleep', {'v':0.,'f':'text 5'}]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
}
```

This doesn't work in the playground nore does it work on my site, When done on my site I will however get the following firebug javascript error:

> Error: Invalid value in 0,1
>   (https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/351cbc565e06280bb093b00ce39323d9/format+en_GB,default,corechart.I.js
>   )

Thanks in advance, I'm probably missing something really obvious

Comment: Is a "litteral string" a sequence of characters that fills the room with trash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this issue, I've gotten the following response from another forum and have used a workaround:

> That is because the arrayToDataTable method does not support the use
>   of the {v: value, f: "formatted value"} object.  I have extrapolated
>   that the method derives the column types from the first row of data,
>   and was not written to handle object entry.  Subsequent rows are
>   likely added via the addRows method (or something like it), thus the
>   object entry works there.  If you want to enter your data like that,
>   you will have to explicitly define your DataTable columns and then use
>   the addRows method.

The workaround is to create a bogus entry and set the value to 0 like follows:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Bogus',0],
    ['Work', {'v':4,'f':'text 1'}],
    ['Eat', {'v':0.,'f':'text 2'}],
    ['Commute', {'v':2,'f':'text 3'}],
    ['Watch TV', {'v':2,'f':'text 4'}],
    ['Sleep', {'v':0.,'f':'text 5'}]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?"});
}
```

Comment: Hello D.Mill, Please give me any idea for how to set custom percentage in google pie chart....

Comment: @GirishPatidar Sorry for the late reply but what to you mean by custom percentage? changing the value of `v` in the above is what will define the % of the slice. If you want to display the percentage (as opposed to the value of the slice) then I think you will need to use variables to calculate it